# Detection of Accident from dataset in R

Tags: r, dataset, row, detection

I have 4 columns in my dataset as frame number,object, mid point of x , mid point of y. I want to detect accident from this dataset. The process which came in my mind was if at same frame number different objects have similar mid point of x and mid point of y value. This will be count as accident. So the thing is whether this data can lead to result or not and How?

```
toler <- 20
dupes <- integer()
for(i in 1:(nrow(accdata)-1)){
   row1 <- accdata[i,]
   for(j in (i+1):nrow(accdata)){
      row2 <- accdata[j,]
      if(all(abs(row1-row2) <= toler)){
         dupes <- c(dupes,i,j)
      }
   }
}
dupes <- sort(unique(dupes))
```

The code which I am trying is giving me the similar data values but I want to add the feature in this that if the (object) column value must not be equal.

```
        Frame Object midx midy
1        26      3   89    214
2        27      3   76    215
3        28      3   45    216
4        29      3   48    216
5        30      3   52    217
6        31      3   54    223
```

This is my dataset. It contains overall 360 rows.

Comment: Are you trying to check the different between the x and y value for each row, or the difference between consecutive x and consecutive y values over multiple rows?

Comment: I am trying to find difference between each row and if it is in the range less than 20 then there is a accident. But the problem is this code is also taking difference between objects and I want to omit this thing from code. I want to take the difference only if the objects value are not same.

Comment: (Assuming the euclidean distance with `midx` and `midy`, if not you need to clarify "range".) Points 1,2 are close (`<20`) as well as 3,4,5 ... so how to you intend to use that knowledge? What if 1 is close to 2, 2 close to 3, 3 to 4, 4 to 5, 5 to 6 (not the case here), what do you intend to happen? It would really help to have the expected output with this sample data.

Comment: The data is extracted from a video which contains accident at frame 73 onwards and when I analysed the data at frame 74 the objects involved in accidents are closer and have difference of around 10-20 in x and y value. So I want to achieve this result with my code.

Comment: This looks like an interesting question but you haven't showed your desired output for the data set provided. In your case all objects are the same, and all the frames are different, hence no result should be produced. I think you should create a more realistic example and show the result you want to get

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this :

```
maxDist <- 20      # max x/y distance
maxFrameDiff <- 10 # max frames range
dupes <- integer()
for(i in 1:(nrow(accdata)-1)){
   row1 <- accdata[i,]
   for(j in (i+1):nrow(accdata)){
      row2 <- accdata[j,]
      if(abs(row1$Frame - row2$Frame) <= maxFrameDiff &&
         abs(row1$midx - row2$midx) <= maxDist &&
         abs(row1$midx - row2$midx) <= maxDist &&
         row1$Object != row2$Object){ # object must be different
         dupes <- c(dupes,i,j)
      }
   }
}
dupes <- sort(unique(dupes))
```

Comment: @ShahzaibAhmed: glad to be of help, and if the answer has been useful, consider accepting it ;)

Comment: I accepted your answer but I don't have enough reputation. Can I achieve same thing in Matlab and how?

Comment: @ShahzaibAhmed: sorry but this is not how StackOverflow works. People asking questions should show a minimum effort in trying to solve their own problem. So far you've asked one question that have been close as off-topic, then this one that is basically identical and now you want me to translate this in MATLAB. No offence, but this is a really simple programming problem; IMO if you improve your basic programming skill you will be perfectly able to solve this on your own and, if after that you still have specific programming issues, come bask and we will be glad to help you ;)